# How do I keep params refreshed?

Tags: angular

How can I keep params refreshed? Right now I have undefined error:

```js
public Id: number;

refreshId($event: Model) {
      this.Id = parseInt($event.Id);
      console.log(this.Id)
  }
```

```html
<app-component [Id]="Id"></app-component>
```

The point is when I click on the table row the id is changed - this part works well but I need this new id to be sent to app-component every change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Subject like below:

Create a service and inject this in both your components.

In the service:

```
public idListerner: Subject

constructor() {
   this.idListerner = new Subject();
}
```

In your component where you are updating it,

```
service.idListener.next(newvalue);
```

In you main component

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.service.idListerner.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res) // This will get printed whenever there is a new value
})
}
```

Comment: not working, Id is null

Comment: Where are you getting it as null?